# How to see/check Build log in D365 Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I executed the BUILD Model in Visual Studio related to Dynamics D365.

[image]

[image]

There is any way to see the log about the last Build executed?
(like Full CIL AX2012 log).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places where log information is provided.

### Details in Build Dialog

The first is the details tab right in the dialog where you execute the model build. The messages there also tell you where you can find log files.
[image]

### VS Output and Error List Pane

The second place is the output and error list pane in Visual Studio. This is documented in [Build results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/build-operations#build-results)

### Log Files

Finally, as already mentioned in the first place, there are log files created in the folder of the model. Which log files are created depends on the options you select in the model build dialog.
[image]